# alsa alsa-store service not found

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, alsa

I had issues with my sound levels using `alsa` - the status was not saved upon shutdown/reboot. Thus, I installed `alsa-utils` package and read the official manual which stated that `alsa-store` service is available, moreover,should be started and enabled.

First, when checking the status in `systemd` running `systemctl status alsa-store` outputs

> Unit alsa-store.service could not be found.

As far as I see it, this is the reason why the sound levels are not stored. Side note - running `alsactl store` saves the levels as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service is called `alsa-restore.service`, not `alsa-store.service`.

This is documented on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture#ALSA_and_Systemd and can be verified by looking at the content of the `alsa-utils` package:

```
# pacman -Ql alsa-utils | grep systemd
alsa-utils /usr/lib/systemd/
alsa-utils /usr/lib/systemd/system/
alsa-utils /usr/lib/systemd/system/alsa-restore.service
alsa-utils /usr/lib/systemd/system/alsa-state.service
```